# Custom Bootstrap 4 fullscreen carousel bug: wrong correspondence between control and caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a full-screen Bootstrap 4 carousel. The slides contain not images, but *videos and captions*.

I have the captions of the *previous and next* slides as *controls*, instead of the "classic" arrows.

For this purpose I have put together some custom CSS and jQuery.

My script does not work right: the content of the *right side control* is not the caption of *next slide*; the content of the *left side control* is not the caption of *previous slide*.

```js
var fullSliderNavigation = function() {
  var slider = $('#full_slider'),
    slide = slider.find('.carousel-item'),
    ctrlNext = slider.find('[data-slide="next"] > span'),
    ctrlPrev = slider.find('[data-slide="prev"] > span');
  slide.each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      var ctrlNextVal = $(this).next().find('.capt').text(),
        ctrlPrevVal = $(this).prev().find('.capt').text();
      ctrlNext.text(ctrlNextVal);
      ctrlPrev.text(ctrlPrevVal);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($('#full_slider').length > 0) {
    fullSliderNavigation();
    $('.carousel-control').on('click', fullSliderNavigation);
  }
  
});
```

```css
/* Slider homepage */

#full_slider .carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.active {
  display: flex !important;
  position: relative;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item-left,
#full_slider .carousel-item-right {
  display: flex !important;
}

#full_slider video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}

#full_slider .video-caption {
  max-width: 595px;
  color: #fff;
}

#full_slider h3 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 100px;
}

#full_slider .control {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#full_slider .carousel-control-next {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#full_slider .carousel-control-prev {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.allcases {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.allcases a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div id="full_slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/koffee.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">All about us</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#"><a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a></a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="//code-love.tk/video/flamenco.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="//code-love.tk/video/protest.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Falling in love</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="//code-love.tk/video/koffe.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Coffe</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="//code-love.tk/video/commerciala.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Dealing with danger</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev" href="#full_slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="control text-left"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-next" href="#full_slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="control text-left"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues on your JavaScript:

1. If you are on the first slide, `prev()` will not find an item. Same goes for the last slide, where you will not find a `next()` item.
2. It seems that at the time of triggering the onclick event, the slide with the class .active is not the new/upcoming slide which you expected, instead its still the old one, which was active right before you click on the next/prev elements.

See my Snippet Example, where I only edited JavaScript of your above version: I use 2 if conditions to handle first and last element. I also used the event which is triggered by bootstrap carousel on its own instead of your custom click event to have the correct active item.

```js
var slider = $('#full_slider');

    var fullSliderNavigation = function(index) {
      var slide = slider.find('.carousel-item').eq(index);

      if (slide.is(':first-child')) {
        var ctrlPrevVal = slide.siblings(":last").find('.capt').text();
      } else {
        var ctrlPrevVal = slide.prev().find('.capt').text();
      }

      if (slide.is(':last-child')) {
        var ctrlNextVal = slide.siblings(":first").find('.capt').text();
      } else {
        var ctrlNextVal = slide.next().find('.capt').text();
      }

      var ctrlNext = slider.find('[data-slide="next"] > span');
      var ctrlPrev = slider.find('[data-slide="prev"] > span');
      ctrlNext.text(ctrlNextVal);
      ctrlPrev.text(ctrlPrevVal);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      fullSliderNavigation(0);

      $(slider).on('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {
        var index = $(event.relatedTarget).index();
        fullSliderNavigation(index);
      });
    });
```

```css
/* Slider homepage */

#full_slider .carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item.active {
  display: flex !important;
  position: relative;
}

#full_slider .carousel-item-left,
#full_slider .carousel-item-right {
  display: flex !important;
}

#full_slider video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}

#full_slider .video-caption {
  max-width: 595px;
  color: #fff;
}

#full_slider h3 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 100px;
}

#full_slider .control {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#full_slider .carousel-control-next {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#full_slider .carousel-control-prev {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.allcases {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.allcases a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div id="full_slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/koffee.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">All about us</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#"><a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a></a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/flamenco.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/protest.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Falling in love</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/commerciala.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Coffe</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <video src="https://code-love.tk/video/commerciala.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
        <div class="video-caption">
          <h3 class="capt text-boldest">Dealing with danger</h3>
          <p class="allcases">
            <a class="inherit" href="#">See more</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev" href="#full_slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="control text-left"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-next" href="#full_slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="control text-left"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
  </div>
</div>
```